# How to apply template to ItemSelector

Tags: extjs

I am using `Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector` in my application. I want to apply conditional XTemplate
to display list. I am using Ext js 4.2 
Please Help me

Comment: Can you post some code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify an itemTpl within the listConfig option.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect-cfg-listConfig